# How to get YEARMONTH (Difference) in a dataframe (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to calculate the months of my date columns (the difference) I have seen that there is a function of java.time for this purpose. I tried to run this on my dataframe, but I get the message:
error: overloaded method value parse with alternatives

Can someone help me?

```
import java.time.YearMonth  
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter  
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit._


val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")

var d1 = df.withColumn("date ", YearMonth.parse($"date_1 ", format))
var d2 = df.withColumn("date ", YearMonth.parse($"date_2 ", format))

val months = d1.until(d2, MONTHS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt function [`months_between`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#months_between-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

```
df.show
//+----------+----------+
//|        d1|        d2|
//+----------+----------+
//|2016-09-20|2018-11-30|
//+----------+----------+


df.printSchema
//root
// |-- d1: date (nullable = true)
// |-- d2: date (nullable = true)

df.withColumn("diff", months_between($"d2", $"d1").cast("int"))
  .withColumn("months_diff" , $"diff" % 12)
  .withColumn("year_diff", ($"diff"/12).cast("int"))
  .show
//+----------+----------+----+-----------+---------+
//|        d1|        d2|diff|months_diff|year_diff|
//+----------+----------+----+-----------+---------+
//|2016-09-20|2018-11-30|  26|          2|        2|
//+----------+----------+----+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: I get different a result. I have i.e. date1 "2018-11-30" date2 "2019-02-22"| and for diff I get "2" and monthdiff "2" or for date1 "2018-11-30" date2 "2018-12-14" I get diff "0" and monthdiff "0". My date columns have also the datatype date (nullable =True)

Comment: @Nika `months_between` returns a `double` value. In the examples that you gave, the difference is in decimal. If you want it to be precise, you can remove `cast("int")` in the code.